# CiviEvent menu listing not finding active event

Tags: civievent, joomla

I'm using CiviCRM 5.1.2 on Joomla 3.8.10. I'm trying to create a menu item for an event info page, and the drop-down in the Joomla menu manager is only displaying past events. The drop-down for the Event Registration Page shows the currently active and upcoming events - there are only 2 of them. But the most recent events in the drop-down for the Event Info page are from 2015. We've been using CiviCRM since 2010, so there are a lot of old events.

I'm assuming there's an issue with where the menu item drop-down is pulling the events from. I've turned on debugging and emptied caches, but otherwise I'm at a loss for what to try next. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drop-down shows 100 active events but does not filter by 'upcoming'.

As a quick-fix, edit the file `administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/joomla/site/elements/civievents.php`
Look for the line that reads `'rowCount' => 100,` (line 62) and add a new line after that reads:

      `'start_date' => array('>' => 'today'),`

Save that and try again.

Issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/1
PR: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-joomla/pull/46

Comment: That did it, thanks so much for finding the quick fix!!

Comment: @LMKWeb could you help by testing the version in the PR which is slightly different and then adding a comment on the ticket that you have tested it - and (hopefully!!) that it works.

Comment: @LMKWeb the PR has been merged so it will be in 5.4.0.  It would be great if you could test the 5.4 rc

Comment: I just tested the updated files - still works great!